# Php mysql query update after 1 day

Tags: php, schedule

Actually i am stuck in logic.

i want after 1 day my query automatic update my ron 0 to 1 (is_new)

```
$timezone = "Asia/Karachi";
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$unixtime =  strtotime("-1440 minutes",strtotime($row['post_date']));
echo $time = date(" d ",$unixtime);
```

so my table row is_new value will change 0 to 1

P.S: what i want.
Ans: i want when some thing add in database is show (New) and after 1 day new automatic will remove. ref : http://i43.tinypic.com/2iv1x0g.png

Comment: setup a cronjob that runs every 24 hours updating the flag, but i don't understand why you don't just use the query to generate this field for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply store a timestamp in your database of when the entry was created, then when you display it on the page, see if it is more than one day old, and remove the "new" tag. Things like this (logic) should not be done in the database, but in your code.

Comment: it stored in database as u can see on my php code but i am stuck in to create logic can you please help me :)

Comment: save your time in an INT field length 11. save the data with the time() function. Then when you display it, just say check if "time < (time()-(60*60*24))", and if it is, then it's older than a day.

Answer (score 0):

Either setup a cron job that executes every few minutes and looks for and updates entries older than a day. This is usually done on system level: create a cron job to execute say every 10 minutes that either calls `wget` or similar to query a url, thus executing some php script served by your http server. Or you can directly execute php on the command line. note that you have different php settings in both cases. 
If you do not have access to the cron system or want to spare the effort of maintaining such a (simple) cron job, then may a `poor mans cron` solution might be of interest: implement a logic in all of your scripts that execute such maintainance tasks. Usually no jobs are overdue, so these tasks don't slow down your normal scripts noticeably. Less flexible, less performant and it only works if you have regular traffic on your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Cron Job to update your record. Cron Jobs are used for scheduling tasks to run on the server. They’re most commonly used for automating system maintenance or administration.

**EG:**

To execute yourscript.php once a day at 2:30AM do the following:

```
# crontab -e
30 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /your home directory/yourscript.php
```

To run the php script using URL from the crontab every day at 2:30AM

```
30 2 * * * lynx -dump http://yoursite.com/yourscript.php
```

You can use tools like [cron job generator](http://www.generateit.net/cron-job/) to generate your code.